# Scrapy: Web scraping not working for certain scenarios

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have re-created a previous code to make use of pandas to make the PowerBi analysis easier. However, I'm running into some issues:

When the code access url: https://www.fcf.cat/acta/2324/futbol-11/juvenil-primera-divisio/grup-2/1j/fundacio-academia-f-lhospitalet-a/1j/fontsanta-fatjo-cd-a

I have tried to add a condition to check if there is a red or yellow booking, however despite there is a red card, the code accounts for it as a yellow card. The logic I'm using to check if there are bookings 'Targetes' does not seem to be 100%. I'm looking for some support to understand what am I doing wrong.

```
import scrapy
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os

class fcf_statsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'fcf_stats'
    start_urls = ["https://www.fcf.cat/calendari/2324/futbol-11/juvenil-primera-divisio/grup-2"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # Extract links from the tables using XPath selector
        links = response.xpath('//*[@class="calendaritablehover"]/a/@href').getall()

        for link in links:
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_match_data)

    def parse_match_data(self, response):
        
        # Extract the HTML content from the Scrapy response
        html_content = response.text
        
        self.temporada = response.css('.acta-info.print-acta-temp::text').get().strip()
        
        # Read all tables from the web page
        tables = pd.read_html(html_content)

        # # Fetch the HTML content of the URL
        # response = requests.get(response)
        # html_content = response.text

        # Create a BeautifulSoup object to parse the HTML
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

        # Extract the elements with class "col-md-4 p-0_ml"
        elements_with_class = soup.find_all(class_="col-md-4 p-0_ml")

        # Check if 'Targetes' is present in elements_with_class[0]
        targetes_in_element_0 = 'Targetes' in elements_with_class[0].get_text()

        # Check if 'Targetes' is present in elements_with_class[2]
        targetes_in_element_2 = 'Targetes' in elements_with_class[2].get_text()

        # Extract the text for the first two elements with class "acta-equip"
        equip_elements = soup.find_all(class_="acta-equip")

        # Check if there are at least two elements with class "acta-equip"
        if len(equip_elements) >= 2:
            eq_local = equip_elements[0].get_text(strip=True)
            eq_visitant = equip_elements[1].get_text(strip=True)
        else:
            # Handle the case where there are not enough elements
            eq_local = None
            eq_visitant = None
            
        # Extract the text of the element with class "acta-info2 print-acta-jornada"
        acta_info = soup.find(class_="acta-info2 print-acta-jornada")
        acta_info_text = acta_info.get_text(strip=True) if acta_info else None

        # Define the column names to filter
        desired_column_names = ['Titulars', 'Suplents', 'Equip Tècnic', 'Targetes', 'Àrbitres', 'Gols', 'Estadi', 'Comparativa']

        # Flag to determine if we've found the first table in desired_column_names
        found_first_table = False

        # Create a dictionary to store tables with matching column names
        table_dict = {}

        # Flags to determine if we've found the first table for each desired column name
        found_first_table_dict = {col_name: False for col_name in desired_column_names}

        # Loop through the tables and append the matching ones to the dictionary
        for table in tables:
            matching_col_name = next((col_name for col_name in desired_column_names if col_name in table.columns), None)
            if matching_col_name:
                # Determine the "Equip" column values based on the conditions
                if matching_col_name == 'Targetes':
                    if targetes_in_element_0 and not found_first_table_dict[matching_col_name]:
                        equip_column_values = [eq_local] * len(table)
                    elif targetes_in_element_2 and not found_first_table_dict[matching_col_name]:
                        equip_column_values = [eq_visitant] * len(table)
                    else:
                        equip_column_values = ['Match_Stats'] * len(table)
                else:
                    equip_column_values = [eq_local if not found_first_table_dict[matching_col_name] else eq_visitant] * len(table)
                
                equip_column = pd.Series(equip_column_values, name='Equip', dtype='object')

                # Create a new DataFrame with the "ActaInfo" column
                acta_info_column = pd.Series([acta_info_text] * len(table), name='ActaInfo', dtype='object')

                # Concatenate the "Equip" and "ActaInfo" columns with the original table
                table = pd.concat([equip_column, acta_info_column, table], axis=1)

                # Update the flag after processing the first table for the current column name
                if not found_first_table_dict[matching_col_name]:
                    found_first_table_dict[matching_col_name] = True

                # Check if a table with the matching column name is already in the dictionary
                if matching_col_name in table_dict:
                    # If it exists, append the current table to it
                    table_dict[matching_col_name] = pd.concat([table_dict[matching_col_name], table], ignore_index=True)
                else:
                    # If it doesn't exist, create a new entry in the dictionary
                    table_dict[matching_col_name] = table
                    
                # Add the "Goal_Type" column to the "Gols" table and set values based on specific class values
                if matching_col_name == 'Gols' and 'Goal_Type' not in table.columns:
                    table['Goal_Type'] = None
                    
                    # Find elements with class values in the HTML content
                    gol_normal_elements = soup.find_all(class_="faf-pilota_base p-a stat-center gol-normal")
                    gol_penal_elements = soup.find_all(class_="faf-pilota_base p-a stat-center gol-penal")
                    gol_propia_elements = soup.find_all(class_="faf-pilota_base p-a stat-center gol-propia")
                    
                    # Set "Goal_Type" based on class values
                    for index, row in table.iterrows():
                        if gol_normal_elements and index < len(gol_normal_elements):
                            table.at[index, 'Goal_Type'] = 'Gol_Normal'
                        elif gol_penal_elements and index < len(gol_penal_elements):
                            table.at[index, 'Goal_Type'] = 'Gol_Penal'
                        elif gol_propia_elements and index < len(gol_propia_elements):
                            table.at[index, 'Goal_Type'] = 'Gol_Propia'
                
                # Add the "Booking" column to the "Targetes" table and set values based on specific class values
                if matching_col_name == 'Targetes' and 'Booking' not in table.columns:
                    table['Booking'] = None

                    # Find elements with class values in the HTML content
                    groga_s_elements = soup.find_all(class_="groga-s")
                    vermella_s_elements = soup.find_all(class_="vermella-s")

                    # Set "Booking" based on class values
                    for index, row in table.iterrows():
                        if groga_s_elements and index < len(groga_s_elements):
                            table.at[index, 'Booking'] = 'Tarjeta Groga'
                        elif vermella_s_elements and index < len(vermella_s_elements):
                            table.at[index, 'Booking'] = 'Targeta Vermella'
                            
        # Save the tables in the dictionary to separate CSV files for each column name
        for col_name, table in table_dict.items():
            csv_filename = f'{col_name}.csv'
            if os.path.exists(csv_filename):
                # If the CSV file already exists, read the existing data
                existing_data = pd.read_csv(csv_filename)
                # Concatenate the existing data with the new data
                table = pd.concat([existing_data, table], ignore_index=True)
            
            # Save the concatenated data (including existing data) back to the same CSV file
            table.to_csv(csv_filename, index=False)
```

Comment: If any of the content is generated or modified using JavaScript, you either need to write your own code to carry out the same actions or to switch to Selenium so your library can execute JavaScript for you.

Comment: Dave S, if the code was not able to detect the bookings under class=groga-s without selenium I would understand, but it is not the case. The code does partially work for class=groga-s but not vermella-s? Have I overlooked at something